# Concatenate two arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 5000x2 array as:

```
A = [1, 3; 2, 4; 1, 6; 2, 4; 1, 7];
```

I have another array of size 100x2 which looks as:

```
B = [1, 14; 2, 15];
```

How can I create a third array where I am going to use column 2 of vector B as follows to modify matrix A:

```
C = [1, 3, 14; 2, 4, 15; 1, 6, 14; 2, 4, 15; 1, 7, 14];
```

I am just trying to use column 1 of B as keys which would be same as contents of column 1 of A.

Comment: Repeat column two as long as nessecary, or take the values corresponding to the first row of A and B? What is the expected output for `B=[2,12;1,11]`?

Comment: B doesn't change. It just has mapping for values in column 2 for keys in column 1.

Comment: Will the number of your rows in A divisible by the rows in B?

Comment: Is the first column in `B = [1 2 3 .. ]`? It's always a good idea to read through the question with the following in mind before posting: "How can this be misunderstood?" If the answer is "It can't": Good! If the answer is something else: It will be misunderstood by someone. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first column on `B` is indices = `1 2 3 4 ...`, the following should work:

```
A = 
     1     3
     2     4
     2     6
     2     4
     1     7
     2     8

C(:,3) = B(A(:,1),2)
C =
     1     3    14
     2     4    15
     2     6    15
     2     4    15
     1     7    14
     2     8    15
```

or if you just want `14 15 14 15`:

```
C = [A repmat(B(:,2),size(A,1)/size(B,1),1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
A(A(:,1)== key ,3) = B(B(:,1)== key ,2);
```

where `key` takes the values of 1 and 2 (and any other possible key).

What does this line do?  `A(:,1)== key` will be true on the rows where the first column values are equal to `key`, and then sets the third column of A equal to the values of B that have the same `key`.

You should execute this line for key=1 and key=2 in order to get what you need.

Comment: It's not scalable cause B is of large size and hence I will need to run a for loop.